# Fullcalendar missing time on date-time for half of hours

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

i run fullcalendar with this options

```
defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:30',
slotDuration: '00:30:00',
events: '/admin/appointment_bookings/calendar.json',
minTime: "08:00:00",
maxTime: "24:00:00",
slotLabelFormat: ['HH:mm'],
timeFormat: 'HH:mm' ,
```

but my date-time only showing for one hours,, the half of hours is not displaying
[image]

i want also to show for half of hours (on the red mark),, i inspect the browser on data-time is already correct,, but it's missing the  for half of hours
[image]

can anyone help me? thx

Comment: Try using slotLabelInterval option something like 00:30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using slotLabelInterval option something like 00:30